# google developer transfer app with subscriptions

Tags: transfer, account, subscriptions

we have developed an app for customer. This app contains subscriptions and we tested them in real world. Then we stop tests and refund all money back. Now, we are unable to transfer app because of active subscriptions (Google told us - after transfer initiaded - that it's not possible, we do not know this... unfortunately). Read so many stories about fact, that this is not possible to change anything if some subscriptions was paid. But Google test payment system didn't work how we expected, so we need to test it in real way... now we are stuck in circle.

Because we have only one app under our account, we agreed with customer to give him logon & other infos in order to get app for him. Unfortunately, we are unable to change country for merchant account. Is it possible to solve this? Or we do need to make new package under customer developer account and then unpublish current app and create a new one with same name?

If unpublish/publish is only way, how can we do this in order to do not hurt any current customer? App is not paid for now. but customer want to start app in new country and want to activate payment system. Unfortunately we are eu residents, and customer seat in Singapore... so we are unable to put his bank account either.

Do we have any options? Or, can we contact Google e.g. by phone? I try to call to Google in CA and have no success.. no live operator, only phone robots there..

Comment: Did you found an answer? I have the same problem.